# I need to move X to right side without solving or simplifying anything else

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I need to manipulate this equation where x is on the left side of the equation. I will be using this in excel and all other numbers will actually be referencing cells so I need x moved to the right side without solving or simplifying anything else.

```
(((60000/26+4410)*2+60000/26)/42)*30.3333=
(((4410/2+((142.8-80)*((142.8x+4410/2)/142.8)*1.5)+80x))*2+(14*6x))/42*30.3333
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: How can you "move x to the right side" without doing some kind of simplification? After all, you have a triply-nested expression involving `x` on the right.

Comment: First I suggest that you gibe a simple example of what you have and what you want. Please avoid the huge numbers and fractions, so that one can understand it from a single glance.Second, your expression is not an equation, but an assignment in Mma, and as it is it should give an error. You should replace `= `by `== `. Third, if I do this, all your expressions involving `x `are already in the right-hand side of the equation, so it is unclear what do you want.

Answer (score 2):

Without simplifying anything else is a bit hard, but you can substitute every number for a symbol, solve for x and then undo the substitution:

```
expr = HoldComplete[(((60000/26 + 4410)*2 + 60000/26)/42)*30.3333 == (((4410/2 + ((142.8 - 80)*((142.8 x + 4410/2)/142.8)*1.5) +80 x))*2 + (14*6 x))/42*30.3333]
```

First, we find all the unique numbers and create a list of subtitutions

```
DeleteDuplicates@Select[Level[expr, {-1}], NumberQ];
nonSymbols = Map[# -> Unique["nn"] &, %]
(* {60000->nn143,26->nn144,-1->nn145,4410->nn146,2->nn147,42->nn148,30.3333->nn149,142.8->nn150,-80->nn151,1.5->nn152,80->nn153,14->nn154,6->nn155} *)
```

Then we apply this substututions to the original expression, and solve for `x`

```
Replace[expr, nonSymbols, {-1}];
sol = Solve[% // ReleaseHold, x]
(* x-> (nn182 nn183^nn184+nn182 nn183^nn184 nn186+nn185 nn186-nn185 nn186^(1+nn184)-nn185 nn186^(1+nn184) nn189^(1+nn184) nn191-nn185 nn186^(1+nn184) nn189^nn184 nn190 nn191)/(nn186 nn189^(2+nn184) nn191+nn186 nn189^(1+nn184) nn190 nn191+nn186 nn192+nn193 nn194) *)
```

Then we undo the substitutions and clean the output a little bit

```
sol /. (nonSymbols /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[b, HoldForm@a])
Replace[%, Power[a_, b_] :> Power[a, ReleaseHold@b], All]
(* x->(-4410 -1.5 4410 + 2 4410 -(-80 1.5 4410) / 142.8 + 60000/26 + (2 60000)/26) / (-80 1.5 2 + 6 14 + 2 80 + 1.5 2 142.8) *)
(* A space between numbers means multiplication *)
```

This is the closest I can get to your original form without losing hair in the process!